# How can I modify a Work Item type to include additional information in TFS?

Tags: tfs, workitem

TFS2008.  I'd like to track task points on a Task work item, but there isn't anywhere (other than the description) to record this.  I'd like to add a dropdown with 0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, etc, so these task points can be exported in reports.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the process template editor, available as part of the [Visual Studio Team System 2008 Team Foundation Server Power Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/tfs2008/bb980963.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I created a web cast awhile ago that demonstrates this tool. it covers a couple of really basic scenarios. It can be accessed [here](http://homepage.mac.com/stevevrporter/blog/Ta.html#vyk233532924).

Ta.

Steve Porter